# How to generate custom image based on user's inputs?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I'm making a quiz for a website with HTML/CSS/JS. Each question in the quiz has a few possible answers that you can choose from. When you complete the quiz, you are given a score from 0-100%.

After the user submits their answers, the user needs to be redirected to another page which will display their score.

On this page, I also need the user to see an image of a line, with the start of the line representing 0% and the end of the line representing 100%.

An image of an arrow should point to the area of the line that represents their percentage score. Here is an image to [image: demonstrate what I mean].

So, my question is: how can I dynamically customize the position of the arrow to suit any possible score from 0-100%?

I have seen a very similar thing done on [this](https://www.politicalcompass.org/test/en) website , which takes your answers to a set of political questions and then gives you a customized image with a point plotted on a graph based on your answers. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please include all relevant code and images in the question.

Comment: You don't need to do the image generation, you can just achieve by html, image and css.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way should be to show the result using html and css.

Code like following I used in one of the project:

```html
<div id="mainDiv">
  <div id="resultArea" style="width:80%;">
    <div style='font-size:50px;display: inline-block; width: 30%; text-align: right;'>&#8615;</div>
      <div id="resultPercentage" style="padding: 10px 0; border: 1px solid #cccccc; background: #cccccc;">
        <span style="float: left; margin-top: 10px;">0</span>
        <span style="float: right;margin-top: 10px;">100</span>
     </div>
   </div>
   <p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
```

Please note, in the div with id "userPercentage", the last style "width: 30%" will move the unicode arrow symbol from 0 to 100..

Answer (score -1):

```
HTML <input> element is used to create interactive controls for web-based forms in order to accept data from the user; a wide variety of types of input data and control widgets are available, depending on the device and user agent.
**HTML:**
<label for="name">Name (4 to 8 characters):</label>

<input type="text" id="name" name="name" required
       minlength="4" maxlength="8" size="10">
**CSS**
label {
    display: block;
    font: 1rem 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
}

input,
label {
    margin: .4rem 0;
}

.note {
    font-size: .8em;
}
```

Comment: I think, the code is not complete. And it didn't serves any purpose to OP's question